# Regarding subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose I have Hilbert space $H$, and two subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$. Somehow I know that $V_1 \cup V_2=H$ and $V_1 \cap V_2 =\{0\}$. I want to show that one of them must be trivial.

I could think of an argument based on Baire catagory. But I want a simple geometric proof to illustrate it. My approach was to take a vector $\mathbf{x}$ and consider the line $\ell = \lambda \mathbf{x}$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar, and then somehow show that any such line is entirely in one of the spaces. But I could not complete the argument. The problem looks very simple though. Any help? Any other approach is equally welcome.

Comment: The subspaces presumably are linear subspaces. Then, think about under which conditions the union of two subspaces is a subspace.

Comment: If $x\in V_{1}$ and $y\in V_{2}$, then $x+y\notin V_{1}$ and $x+y\notin V_{2}$
which is impoosible.

Comment: @user72012 you mean when $x \neq 0 \neq y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments have already pointed out, the proof is entirely linear algebraic.

A union of two vector (sub)subspaces $V_1, V_2$ is a vector space if and only if $V_1\subset V_2$ or $V_2\subset V_1$.  (Proof: suppose not, then take $x\in V_1\backslash V_2, y\in V_2\backslash V_1$, and conclude $x+y\notin V_1\cup V_2$).

In this case, since $V_1\cup V_2 = H$, we have $V_1\subset V_2$ or $V_2\subset V_1$, and hence $V_1\cap V_2 = \{0\} \implies V_1=\{0\} \text{ or } V_2=\{0\}$